# Get interval of binary search tree as fast as sorted array

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

Currently I am implementing BST in Java for my university project. As we know, BST is quite good in searching a **single** unit which is O(log n) in a balanced tree.

But how to perform search between value `a` and `b`? (a < b)

Let's say I have this tree

```
│               ┌── 125
│           ┌── 122
│           │   └── 120
│       ┌── 117
│       │   │   ┌── 113
│       │   └── 112
│       │       └── 108
│   ┌── 86
│   │   │   ┌── 85
│   │   └── 72
└── 59
    │           ┌── 56
    │       ┌── 52
    │   ┌── 47
    │   │   │   ┌── 43
    │   │   └── 39
    │   │       │   ┌── 38
    │   │       └── 36
    └── 28
        │       ┌── 18
        │   ┌── 15
        └── 2
            └── 1
```

I want to create a method `range(a,b)` to return value between `a` and `b` inclusive. (Note: `a` and `b` are not necessary in the tree!)

For example: `range(53,112)` will return `56,59,72,85,86,108,112`

Here is my pseudo code

```
/* recursive method */
range(a,b)
    range(a,b,root);

/* helper method */
range(a,b,node)
    if (a <= node.value <= b)
        if (node.left != null) and (node.value != a)
            range(a,b,node.left)

        print node.value

        if (node.right != null) and (node.value != b)
            range(a,b,node.right)

    else if node.value < a
        if (node.right != null)
            range(a,b,node.right)

    else // node.value > b
        if (node.left != null)
            range(a,b,node.left)
```

But I think my method is slower.

For example, in a sorted array, we have to perform binary search on `a` and `b` and get their respective index. After that, we iterate from index of `a` to index of `b`.

Is it true that BST will perform slower on searching multiple values? Is it possible to improve my algorithm to be as fast as a sorted array?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you can return the result, a sorted array may have the huge advantage of not needing to copy the results anywhere.  Just returning a pointer+length view into the array is far faster and more cache-friendly than making another copy of the range into another buffer.  A tree always has to copy elements out of the tree.  Even if you do need a copy (to modify or whatever), memcpy is much much faster than walking a tree.

This isn't an issue if you can process on the fly while walking the tree (like you're doing with `print`).

I always seem to write answers before googling.  It turns out that [trees to answer range queries are a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).  Apparently it's usually done for 2D or 3D ranges (where each point has x and y coordinates, for example), which you can't do with a sorted array.  I assume this is because even though it's as efficient as possible, it's not as efficient as returning a pointer+length window into a sorted array!

I'm not going to copy/paste the whole algorithm from wikipedia, just the clever idea:

> To report the points that lie in the interval [x1, x2], we start by
>   searching for x1 and x2. At some vertex in the tree, the **search paths
>   to x1 and x2 will diverge**

This is how you efficiently detect whole subtrees that you know will be in your range, see wikipedia and/or google "tree range query" for lots of details.

---

My pre-googling observation was that you could avoid comparisons and just walk some subtrees.  In your example, the left subtree of `86` is guaranteed to all be in the range, because we know they're all >59 and <86, which is a tighter bound than `[a..b]`.  I hadn't thought of a way to look for this special case that wouldn't maybe cost more overhead than it saved.